# Search on a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net

How to search an item, using item's property, from a list of Objects in C#?

```
public Class IDDesc
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}

List<IDDesc>list = new List<IDDesc>();
int index=list.BinarySearch(list.Description.Contains("C"));
```

Comment: same as doing a binary search in any other language

Comment: Unless you sort your list, binary search ain't gonna work.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @spender even with sorted list the condition is not applicable to binary search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you are looking for is a `Find`

```
IDDesc result = list.Find(item => item.Description.Contains("C"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you understand what binary search is?

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm):

> In computer science, a binary search or half-interval search algorithm finds the position of a **specified input value** (the search "key") within an **array sorted by key** value

You don't have sorted collection and you're not looking for a key. You're looking for all items matching `x.Description.Contains("C")` condition.

**Binary search is not a way to go here.**

You can get what you need with standard linear search using LINQ:

```
int index = list.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
                .First(x => x.Value.Description.Contains("C"))
                .Index;
```

Comment: Please show me how you would do what I am trying to do.

Comment: Mate, he asked for the BinarySearch and you gave him a linear one, that is clearly will not help him or will be effective for huge datas.

Comment: He can't do a binary search for "contains".

Comment: @OrelEraki Did you read my answer? Binary search is not a way to go if he needs `Contains` condition.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, Yes I've read your answer, he only needs to know the downsides of every method he chooses. If it's a BinarySearch than he must maintain a sorted List. If it's a linear search than Complexity will have to be consider.

Comment: My apologies, didn't noticed the "Contains" part. He could do it with BinarySearch and Comparators/Comparable but it's doesn't worth the complexity code costs.

Comment: @OrelEraki You could if it was a "Starts With" instead of a "Contains" but because you are not doing a "Starts With" or "Equals" BinarySearch is not applicable at all.

Answer (score 0):

First you should implement the interface IComparable in your object as in the exemple:

```
    public class IDDesc : IComparable<IDDesc>
    {    
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(IDDesc other)
        {
        //     A value that indicates the relative order of the objects being compared.
        //     The return value has the following meanings: Value Meaning Less than zero
        //     This object is less than the other parameter.Zero This object is equal to
        //     other. Greater than zero This object is greater than other.
             int ret = -1;
             if (this.ID > other.ID)
                 ret = 1;
             else if (this.ID == other.ID)
                 ret = 0;

             return ret;
        }
    }
```

And then you can create a method that does the BinarySearch which would look like something like that:

```
    public IDDesc GetIDDescByID(int ID)
    {
        IDDesc toFind = new IDDesc();
        toFind.ID = ID;
        //List Items must be sorted!
        list.Sort();
        int foundIndex = list.BinarySearch(toFind);
        if (foundIndex > -1)
            toFind = list[foundIndex];

        return toFind;
    }
```